# SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression 00936. 00000 - "missing expression" *Cause: *Action:

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I'm trying write an update statement that changes the passwords of customers who placed more than one
order to excellent, which contains all lowercase characters:

```
UPDATE customers_mgs
SET password = 'excellent'
WHERE customer_id = SELECT customer_id FROM customers_mgs WHERE count(>1 group by customer_id)
```

But I keep getting this error message:
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Comment: It is really strange that you would store the password in a table called `customer_msgs` -- and also that you would store a password in clear text.

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around a subquery.  Presumably, you also want `IN` rather than `=`:

```
UPDATE customers_mgs
    SET password = 'excellent'
    WHERE customer_id IN (SELECT customer_id
                          FROM customers_mgs 
                          GROUP BY customer_id
                          HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
                         );
```